# Install Malayalam true type fonts

Tags: fonts

How to Install Malayalam windows fonts (.ttf) in my Ubuntu 12.04 using to create douments with Libre Office, Gimp etc.

Comment: Do you mean that you already have those font files and want to install them? Or do you mean that you are looking for Malayalam font files?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the font files, just open nautilus, navigate to the file and open it with font viewer. There's a button "Install font".

If you have the fonts installed in Windows, you could navigate to the Windows fonts directory and do the above procedure.